# Settings permissions on /var/www

Tags: apache-http-server, file-transfer, sftp, www

I'm running ubuntu server and have apache installed as a web server. I'm letting my web developers upload files through sftp (ssh) to /var/www. I'm using www-data group to control access to /var/www folder. They are able to upload the files successfully but when they try to access that file in a browser, they get a 403 forbidden error.

How do I make sure that when the files are uploaded, the permissions are set right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a terminal, type

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/
```

If that still doesn't work, try

```
sudo chown www-data /var/www
```

Failing this, post the output of  **ls -l /var** so we can rule out file permissions.